# Sticky footer makes page scroll further

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

This issue is happening with Chrome (up-to-date) on both mac and windows.

The footer, which is stuck to the bottom of the page, is making the page scroll longer than it should.

You can [view the issue here](http://cpp.drfortress.com/?page_id=304).

Our developer, who is much more skilled than myself, says that there is no problem with the code. Thoughts?

Comment: All I see is this: http://i.imgur.com/iywOGDp.png  Seems to work correct?

Comment: Seems to look perfectly fine to me. Tested in Chrome.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it's a window-height thing? windows - 25" monitor; mac - 27" monitor. See red circle: http://www.goosedigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Screen-Shot-2015-08-25-at-10.03.28-AM.png

Comment: I still can't see the problem. Part of the footer is out of the window, so you have to scroll a little to see the entire footer.

Comment: ^ That's the problem.

Comment: Do you have fixed height defined on the container element above the footer?

Comment: Hi Krishna, the container above is the content area and no, it doesn't have a fixed height. It has padding, but the padding isn't pushing down the footer in this case.